# Minimizing Euclidean norm plus a linear function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, normed-spaces

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to minimize the following with respect to $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$$ f(y) = \| y \| + \lambda^T y $$

where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm. I first take the derivative of the function and get

$$ \nabla f(y) = \frac{y}{\| y \|} + \lambda $$

Then I tried to get the Hessian matrix but I could not conclude anything. Is $f$ a convex function? If not, how can I find the minimum of this function?

Comment: It is convex, because it is the sum of two convex functions.

Comment: Baby case: $n=1$. The minimum is $0$ if $-1\leq \lambda\leq 1$, and there is no minimum otherwise as the infimum is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\|y\|+\langle \lambda,y\rangle\geq \|y\|(1-\|\lambda\|) $$

From the last inequality we conclude that if $\|\lambda\|\in [0,1]$, then the minimum of $f$ is zero.

On the other hand, if $\|\lambda\|>1$, you can take $y=-t\lambda$, and make $t\rightarrow\infty$ to conclude that $f(-t\lambda)\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: From the last inequality if $||\lambda|| \in [0,1]$, then the minimum of the function in the right is zero. How can you conclude that $f$ is also zero?

Comment: Note that $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $y'$ is a minimum and is not 0, then let $c>0$,

Then $f(cy') = ||cy'|| + c\lambda^Ty'=c( ||y'|| + \lambda^Ty') $

This function is zero at zero, so you're not gonna get a minimum that is less than zero by this calculation.